# In AngularJS, is there any side effect if you use module.service() when module.factory() should be used?

Tags: angularjs

I saw some code in the existing code base:

```
angular.module("myApp", [])
    .service("myService", function() {
        return {
            getData: function() { } // etc ...
        };
    });
```

I think the concept is this: if it is `module.factory()`, you provide a function to return an object (which is the service object), versus, if it is `module.service()`, you provide a function, which is in fact just a constructor function, so that later on, a `new` keyword will be used with this constructor function to obtain the service object.

However, the code above surprisingly actually works.  It apparently is due to the fact that, if it is taken to be a constructor function (even though it is not), when the `new` keyword is used with it, it returns an object, so this object is return instead of the object instantiated with the `new` keyword.  But the fact is, it still works.

So is it true that even when we should use `module.factory()`, using `module.service()` actually works.  Is there any side effect?

I think it is best to be changed back to `module.factory()`, but at the same time, I am afraid if everything works now, changing it back to `module.factory()` may introduce new bugs.

Comment: you should change it to factory... it was defined as service by mistake mostly

Comment: doubt it would break changing `service` to `factory` although curious why `new` was used with it in first place